# Python eyeD3 Syntax Error on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, eyed3

Need some help here.

Been on this for hours, i'm trying to install/use `eyeD3` - a Python based ID3 editor on my Windows 10 machine and I've been getting this error,

```
C:\Python\Python27\eyeD3\bin>python eyeD3
  File "eyeD3", line 3
    python -m eyed3.main "$@"
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I opened the file and its content is,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python -m eyed3.main "$@"
```

I have searched and searched and it's as if i'm the first person to face this problem, i have no experience with Python and i can't understand how an integer will cause a syntax error.

I have tried installing the package with `pip`, uninstalling the package installing with `python setup.py install` using Python 2.7 as recommended, trying Python 3.1, even using quotes on the `"eyed3.main"` yet no success.

Any ideas please?

Comment: eyed3.main appears to be a bash script rather than python.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in a terminal :

```
easy_install -U pip
```

and then :

```
pip install eyeD3
```